# Clang : invalid operands to binary expression ('const auto' and 'int') with constexpr template variable that depends on template context

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, c++20, clang++

```
Clang error : invalid operands to binary expression ('const auto' and 'int')
```

Context :

- Clang 12.0.0

Simple questions :

- What does this error means in this context ? *(e.g is the message relevant here ?)*
- Why does this error only occur when compiling with Clang, in opposition to GCC and Msvc-cl ?

Here is a minimal reproduction case *(available [here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ofveeGoWe))*

```cpp
template <typename ... Ts>
struct foo
{
    constexpr inline static auto value = 42;
};

template <typename ... Ts>
struct bar
{
    template <typename U>
    constexpr static inline auto foo_value = foo<Ts...>::value; // Error here
    // nb : replacing `auto` with `int` remove the error
};

static_assert(bar<int>::foo_value<int> == 42); // K.O : invalid operands to binary expression ('const auto' and 'int')
```

Looks like Clang cannot evaluate an `auto` type that depends on another `auto`, when both depends on template context.

[author edit] Maybe in correlation with https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43459

Comment: What is the purpose of `template <typename U>` for `foo_value`?  It doesn't depend on it at all.  If remove that, and change the `stattic_assert` to `static_assert(bar<int>::foo_value == 42);` it works with all of the compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/hhGrWGqTv

Comment: @NathanOliver it should be obvious that this is result of minimizing example. Does this make you happy: https://godbolt.org/z/88dWd41fr

Comment: @NathanOliver This is a minimal example to reproduce the error. In real world, every template parameters have specific purpose ofc.

Comment: Seems a clang++ bug, introduced from version 9.0.0.

Comment: Fixed in Clang 13: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/W4cq8KK5M